# Attiny85 Watchdog fires only once

Tags: interrupt, attiny, watchdog

I build something like a flashlamp with different modi. From the hardware site it's quite simmilar to the Nanjg105c. 
There is a Attiny85 which generates a PWM signal to an AMC7135.

I have one push button, if I click it the Attiny go to sleep, if I hold the button the Attiny changes his mode. 
[image]
For checking the battery voltage I use the watchdog timer to make the ADC conversion every 8sec.

```
    #include "OneButton.h"
#include <avr/sleep.h>               // Sleep Modes
#include <avr/power.h>              // Power management
#include <avr/wdt.h>              // Watchdog Timer
#include <util/delay.h>

#define mid 4000                // BAttery Level Mid
#define low 3200                // Battery Level low, flash and start dimming the Led
#define crit 2600               // Battery Level critical, shut down


const byte LEDr = 1;              // pin 1
const byte LEDw = 4;              // pin 4
const byte ModeNr = 3;
volatile bool WDR_flag = false;
bool PWR_flag = false;

OneButton button1(2, true);
int count = 1;
int flag = 0;
long Vcc;
int PWMr = 255;
int PWMw_l = 50;
int PWMw_h = 255;

ISR(PCINT0_vect)
{
    // do something interesting here
}

ISR(WDT_vect){
  WDR_flag=true;
 }

void setup()
{
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LEDr, OUTPUT);            // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    pinMode(LEDw, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(LEDr, HIGH);           // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    digitalWrite(LEDw, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    button1.attachClick(sleep);
    button1.attachLongPressStart(changeMode);
    WDT_on();
}

void loop()
{
  uint8_t i = 0;
    button1.tick();               // keep watching the push buttons:
  if(WDR_flag == true){           // do every 8s 
    WDR_flag = false;           //reset WDT Flag
    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);      //debug with third LED
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    WDT_off();
    //ADC_on();
    /*Vcc = readVcc();            //read Battery voltage
    if(Vcc < low && count == 3){
      if(PWMw_h <= PWMw_l){       //change Mode to low when PWM output is smaler then low PWM
        count = 2;
      }else
    {
    i = 0;
        while (i++<3 && PWR_flag == false) {         //flash 3 times the red LED befor dimm the white LED
          analogWrite(LEDr, PWMr);
          _delay_ms(500);
          digitalWrite(LEDr, LOW);
          _delay_ms(250);
      PWR_flag = true;
        }     
      PWMw_h = PWMw_h / 2;        //halve the PWM output of the white LED
      }
      if(Vcc <= crit){          //go to sleep when Battery is empty
        sleep();
      }
    }
    if(Vcc < low && count == 1){
      i = 0;
      while (i++<3) {
        digitalWrite(LEDr, LOW);
        _delay_ms(250);
        analogWrite(LEDr, PWMr);
        _delay_ms(500);
        }
      PWMr = PWMr / 2;
      if(Vcc <= crit){
        sleep();  
      }
    }*/
    //ADC_off();                //save power  
    WDT_on;                 //start watchdog again

  }
  switch (count) {
    case 1:                 //Mode red LED 
    analogWrite(LEDr, PWMr);
    digitalWrite(LEDw, LOW);
    break;
  case 2:                   //low Mode white LED
    digitalWrite(LEDr, LOW);
    analogWrite(LEDw, PWMw_l);
    break;
  case 3:                   //high Mode white LED
    digitalWrite(LEDr, LOW);
    analogWrite(LEDw, PWMw_h);
    break;
  }
}



void sleep()                  // This function will be called when the button1 was pressed 1 time
{
    digitalWrite(LEDr, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LEDw, LOW);
    //prepare sleep
    WDT_off();
    GIFR |= bit(PCIF);              // clear any outstanding interrupts
    GIMSK |= _BV(PCIE);             // Enable Pin Change Interrupts
    PCMSK |= _BV(PCINT2);             // Use PB2 as interrupt pin
    ADC_off();
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);    // replaces above statement

    sleep_enable();               // Sets the Sleep Enable bit in the MCUCR Register (SE BIT)
    sei();                    // Enable interrupts
    sleep_cpu();                // sleep

    cli();                    // Disable interrupts
    PCMSK &= ~_BV(PCINT2);            // Turn off PB2 as interrupt pin
    sleep_disable();              // Clear SE bit
    WDT_on();

    flag = 1;                 //set flag, uc was in sleepmode before
} 

void changeMode()               // This function will be called once, during pressed for a long time.
{
    if (flag == 1) {
        flag = 0;
    }
    else {
        if (count < ModeNr) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            count = 1;
        }
    }
}

void WDT_on() {
  // Setup watchdog timer to only interrupt, not reset
  cli();                    // Disable interrupts
  wdt_reset();                // Reset the WDT
  WDTCR |= (1 << WDCE) | (1 << WDE);       // Start timed sequence
  WDTCR = (1 << WDIE) | (1 << WDP3) | (1<<WDP0);      // Watchdog cycle = 8 s
  //WDTCR = (1 << WDIE);             // Watchdog Interrupt enable
  sei();                    // Enable interrupts
}

void WDT_off(){
  cli();                    // Disable interrupts
  wdt_reset();                // Reset the WDT
  MCUSR &= ~(1<<WDRF);            // Clear Watchdog reset flag
  WDTCR |= (1<<WDCE) | (1<<WDE);        // Start timed sequence
  WDTCR = 0x00;               // Disable WDT
  sei();                    // Enable interrupts
}

void ADC_on() {
  ADCSRA = (1 << ADEN );            // ADC power on
}

void ADC_off() {
  ADCSRA &= ~(1<<7);              //ADC off
}

long readVcc() {
  // Read 1.1V reference against AVcc
  // set the reference to Vcc and the measurement to the internal 1.1V reference

  ADMUX = _BV(MUX3) | _BV(MUX2);
  delay(2);                  // Wait for Vref to settle
  ADCSRA |= _BV(ADSC);              // Start conversion
  while (bit_is_set(ADCSRA,ADSC));        // measuring

  uint8_t low_adc  = ADCL;              // must read ADCL first - it then locks ADCH  
  uint8_t high_adc = ADCH;              // unlocks both

  long result = (high_adc<<8) | low_adc;

  result = 1126400L / result;           // Calculate Vcc (in mV); 1126400 = 1.1*1024*1000
  int x = 0;
  /*while (x++<2) {         //debug with third LED
          digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
          _delay_ms(500);
          digitalWrite(3, LOW);
          _delay_ms(250);
        } */  
  return result;                // Vcc in millivolts
}
```

my problem is that the watchdog fires only once. after putting the attiny to sleep the watchdog fires also only once.

I think the problem is in the WDT_off() function...

Answer (score 2):

The line below lacks parens `()` to make it a function call; as it stands, it's not actually calling `WDT_on`.

```
WDT_on;                 //start watchdog again
```

should be:

```
WDT_on();                 //start watchdog again
```